# How to stop working constructor in C#?

Tags: c#

Here's typical class.

```
class Round
{
    private int radius;

    private bool Validate(int radius) 
    {

            if (radius <= 0)
            {
            return false;
            }
            else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public int X { get; set;}
    public int Y { get; set;}

    public int Radius
    {
        get
        {
            return radius;
        }

        set
        {
            try
            {   
                if(!Validate(value))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }
            radius = value;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ooops... something went wrong.");
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    public Round (int X, int Y, int radius)
    {

        try
        {
            if (!Validate(radius))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.radius = radius;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ooops... something went wrong.");
        }
    }

    public double GetPerimeter()
    {
        return Math.PI * radius * 2;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Round r = new Round(0,0,0);
        Console.WriteLine(r.GetPerimeter());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I send incorrect value to constructor that sends the value to validator. I can't understand what should I do to make constructor stop creating object ???.

Comment: If something unexpected occurs in a constructor, you throw an `Exception`.  If you don't want to throw an exception, you could have a static class method for generating instances of the class ("Factory").

Comment: You can't stop constructor but you can throwing exception

Comment: You can both react to an exception *and* let it propagate to outer level by rethrowing it. In `catch` block replace `return` with `throw`.

Answer (score 5):

The way to stop a constructor is to throw an exception.

You are doing that, but then you are also catching the exception. That way, the constructor will continue. Don't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to throw exception in constructor, you could consider this method

```
// constructor
public Round (int X, int Y, int radius)
{
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
    this.radius = radius;
}

// create instance
public static Round CreateInstance(int X, int Y, int radius)
{
    if (!Validate(radius))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return new Round(X, Y, radius);
}
```

How to use:

```
// invalid should be null
Round invalid = Row.CreateInstance(1, 1, -1);
```